# Passing an array argument from C# to a C++/CLI method

Tags: c#, c++-cli, parameter-passing

I know only very little about C++/CLI, but I have a simple problem that needs a solution. I have a C++/CLI class method that takes a byte-array as a parameter. The array is of a pre-determined length, and can be allocated in C# beforehand. The array is supposed to be filled with data by the C++/CLI method.

How do I declare the method and then call it from C#?

I tried something like having the following in my C++/CLI class:

```
public ref class C
{
public:
    void FillBytes(array<BYTE^>^ bytes);
};
```

And then, in C#:

```
o = new C();
var bytes = new byte[3];
o.FillBytes(bytes);
```

But that didn't work at all :).

Comment: I made a typo at first, when I wrote `array<BOOL^>^` instead of `array<BYTE^>^`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using `byte` instead of a `BOOL` reference?

```
void FillBytes(array<System::Byte>^ bytes);
                                ↑
                           //   no ^ here
```

Comment: Oops, I just typed in some simplified version of my actual code and made a typo. But the problem still remains. I get "Argument '1': cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'System.ValueType[]'", when trying to compile the above code.

Answer (score 10):

I know this question was asked a long time ago but hopefully it will help someone else who is checking this post. From C++/CLI you need to send this:

```
void FillBytes(array<unsigned char>^% bytes);
```

The "hat" means its a CLR type and the % means you will pass it by reference so that the C++/CLI fills the array.

Then you can call it from C# like this:

```
o = new C();
var bytes = new byte[3];
o.FillBytes(ref bytes);
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: How would you change this for a dynamic  array?